# Strange "&#65279" character after upgrading to Asp.Net Core RC2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

After I upgraded to Asp.Net RC2 a couple of strange things started happening. I first thought that it might have something to do with how I ported my app. But creating a new default web app produces the same result when I run it:

[image]

Notice how everything in the head is now in the body (no idea why). This is causing some visual problems.
This is one (along a couple others), there is a gap after the navbar and before the body:

[image]

After a while I tried running in Edge and Firefox, and it seems the problem only happens on Google Chrome.
I absolutely made sure I have no BOM characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue with BrowserLink: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4671

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Tratcher it's an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4671) with BrowserLink. If you're not using it, just comment the line in Startup.cs that activates BrowserLink:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    //app.UseBrowserLink();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I don't use browser link. Check if there an **Empty Line** at the start of any `.cshtml` doc. Mostly its in the `_Layout.cshtml`. This worked for me.

Comment: In my case the line wasn't blank but the very first character was the &#65279 - invisible but deleteable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, in my **.cshtml** file was UTF-8-BOM, I did use notepad++ to open the file and then switched using notepad++ Hexa editor plugin and noticed there was an invisible character just in front of **@model**. I did remove that character and changed the encoding of the file to UTF-8 and fixed the issue.

[image]